# Can Ubuntu for tablets run Java applets?

Tags: java, android, tablet

Can Ubuntu for tablets run JAVA applets in browser? My bank has netbanking build in Java and I need to use it on my android tablet which does not support Java browser applets. Don't have experience with Linux (I am Windows user), and don't know much about Java support on Linux. I don't need to run native android apps, just need to install JRE on Ubuntu for tablets(first install Ubuntu on my android tablet, ASUS Transformer Pad TF300T) and run that applet. Is that possible?

Comment: You can also use [Complete Linux Installer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.zpwebsites.linuxonandroid) to run Ubuntu inside Android without installing it completely. Java (OpenJDK) works fine, but it is a bit laggy and audio does not work. Anyway you need to root your device. I recommend using the 13.04 small image if you do.